# How to find out MINIMUM requirements when making a .deb package?

Tags: cmake, debian, cpack

I'm currently trying to package a software that uses CMake to a .deb package. I've managed to modify the CMakeLists.txt to use CPack and create a .deb file. But one thing that I have not managed to find out even with extensive googling is how do I find out what the CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_DEPENDS variable should contain as dependencies?

I can find out what dependencies the software has on MY computer but how do I find out what the MINIMUM dependencies are? There must be some automatic way of doing this...?

I can see some dependencies from the CMake file but those are for building the project, I want to know what dependencies the binary has.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
# autogenerate dependency information
set (CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_SHLIBDEPS ON)
```

See also 
[Auto-Detect Dependencies when Building .debs Using CMake](http://www.guyrutenberg.com/2012/07/19/auto-detect-dependencies-when-building-debs-using-cmake/)

Answer (score 0):

Using CMake I'm not aware of a way to "detect" such dependencies automatically.

I think it is also the job of the **packager** to know what are gonna be the dependencies.

I would suggest you try into a **virtual machine** with a **fresh install** of your system.